# What is the process to clean up orphaned dynamic creds in Hashicorp Vault?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am using Hashicorp Vault to generate dynamic creds in multiple database clusters.  We have one database cluster that is somewhat ephemeral so on occasion it will be refreshed from another database cluster.  This database cluster will be connected to via Vault dynamic creds just like the other database clusters.

I have the process to clean up the database users brought over by the backup from the source system when this cluster is refreshed but I don't know how I should handle the Vault cleanup.  The database config will be the same (same host/user) but all the existing database user accounts recently created by Vault will be gone after the refresh so I don't know what I need to do to reset/clean up Vault for that database.  The database system I'm using (Redshift) doesn't seem to have `DROP USER ... IF EXISTS` type of syntax otherwise I would simply use that in the dynamic role's revocation_statements and let it cycle out naturally that way.

So my main question is how do I reset or delete all the dynamic creds that were created for a specific database cluster in Vault if the database cluster is refreshed or no longer exists?

Comment: Is the `ttl` for the creds super long? They should just expire.

Comment: @MattSchuchard they are failing to clean up because the revocation_statements fails since the DB user no longer exists after it is refreshed (restored from backup)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to this and I wanted to share here in case anyone else encounters this.

[The "lease revoke" documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/lease/revoke#examples) explains that you can use the `-prefix` switch to revoke leases based on a partial or full prefix match.

Using this information you can run a command similar to the following in order to force revoke existing leases for a specific role:

`vault lease revoke -force -prefix database/creds/ROLE_NAME`

Using the `-force` switch will remove the lease even if the `revocation_statements` fails to process (case when the database user no longer exists).

As an aside, the following command can be used to list leases and is useful to check before and after that all the leases are, in fact, revoked:

`vault list sys/leases/lookup/database/creds/ROLE_NAME`

This solves my problem of "how to I remove leases for orphaned Vault dynamic credentials" in cases where the target database is refreshed from a backup which is the case I am using this for.